# Missing Quadrilateral Angle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle, quadrilateral

Please find the missing green angle for the quadrilateral using simple geometry and explain your steps. I am not able to use trigonometry for this problem. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Hint: the 80-50-50 triangle on the left is isosceles, and the 60-60-60 triangle on the right is equilateral. What can you say about their sides?

Comment: Why did you not label the vertices in your diagram? It is easy to give a hint that way. Anyway you have an isosceles triangle in the middle with one angle being 40. So other two are ? . That leads to the answer.

Comment: Did you only get the solid coloured angles to start? Seems like you made quite a bit of progress, and maybe you just needed to find the extra two lines that are the same length as those marked $\parallel$

Answer (score 1):

$ABCD$ is cyclic so the opposite angles are supplementary

$\angle BCD=130°\to \angle ACD=130°-90°=40°$

Or since it's cyclic we can use the inscribed angle. The central angle is already given as $80°$.

So $\angle ACD=\frac12\,80°=40°$
[image]

Comment: Also since it's cyclic you can use the inscribed angle. The central angle is already given as $80$ degrees.